# Scala Maven Compiler: NullPointerException

Tags: scala, maven

I have just moved a project from scala 2.11.11 to 2.12.6

My build now throws the following exception:

> error: java.lang.NullPointerException [INFO]  at
>   scala.tools.nsc.transform.patmat.MatchTranslation$MatchTranslator.translateMatch(MatchTranslation.scala:215)

My pom.xml is below. Any advice on how to troubleshoot would be appreciated. The internet does not have any discussion of this issue

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>ikoda</groupId>
    <artifactId>scalaML</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <inceptionYear>2008</inceptionYear>
    <properties>
        <scala.version>2.12.6</scala.version>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>${scala.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.specs</groupId>
            <artifactId>specs</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.clapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>grizzled-slf4j_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>




        <!---spark-->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql_2.11 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>

        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-lang/scala-reflect -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-reflect</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>15.0</version>

        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming_2.11 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>

        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-mllib_2.11 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-graphx_2.11 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-graphx_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe/config -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe</groupId>
            <artifactId>config</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json4s</groupId>
            <artifactId>json4s-core_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0-M4</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.scopt/scopt -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.scopt</groupId>
            <artifactId>scopt_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>

        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>ikoda</groupId>
            <artifactId>ikoda-utils</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ikoda</groupId>
            <artifactId>ikodatext-textAnalysis</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.7</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
            <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>


            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
            <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <classifier>models</classifier>

            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
            <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <classifier>models-chinese</classifier>

            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
            <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <classifier>models-english</classifier>

            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/edu.stanford.nlp/stanford-parser -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
            <artifactId>stanford-parser</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-math3 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>

        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.pathikrit/better-files -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.pathikrit</groupId>
            <artifactId>better-files_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>

        </dependency>

    </dependencies>



    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- exclude log4j.properties -->
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/log4j.properties</exclude>
                    </excludes>

                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>create-archive</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>


        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: there are discussions https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9963 and https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-10090

Comment: unresolved from 2016 :( How do I get around this. What do I need to change?

Comment: change your scala version to 2.11.8 and you should be fine I guess

Comment: well, I was on 2.11.11...I guess I have to go back.

Comment: @Ramesh, any idea why I am getting this? Nobody else seems to have the problem.

Comment: i guess its the version compatibility . You are using scala 2.12.6. but for spark libraries you are using 2.11 compiled versions. They are not compatible i guess. so either you go with 2.11 scala or you upgrade your spark libraries compiled in 2.12 scala.